# How to plot values against letters

Tags: matlab, plot

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b is a cell array "a", "b", "c", "d"
```

I want to plot a VS b in matlab. and show the labels on the axis

Comment: What is a *VS b* ? Do you want a bar chart? You can change the labels on the axis using the tick label properties

Comment: You can set `xTickLabel` property of the axes...